# Laptop with two LUKS encrypted disks: HDD and SSD: How to start with same passphrase?

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

In my Linux laptop I've two disks:
One larger conventional HDD and a smaller but fast SSD.
On the SSD I've got a small unencrypted `/boot`-Partition containing kernels, initrd images, and GRUB. All remaining stuff (including the Linux `/`, `swap`, `/home`, ...) is in two [LUKS](https://superuser.com/q/33514/237148) encrypted pseudo devices.  These are started at boot time using entries in `/etc/crypttab`.  Everything works just fine.

But during booting, I've to enter two passphrases to activate both LUKS container.

Since I've used the same passphrase for both disks I'm now looking for a clever and secure way which allows me to start both disks by entering the passphrase only once during boot.  Any ideas?

I already know that I could store the passphrase for the second disk in a keyfile on the already encrypted root filesystem on the SSD and refer to it in the `/etc/crypttab` file.  But I fear this key file might leak somehow (possibly
it might show up in the initrd images on unencrypted `/boot/` partition?).

Comment: I don't suppose any initramfs generation utility (mkinitcpio, dracut...) would include `/etc/crypttab` to the initramfs, unless the user for some reason explicitly configure it to do so (but then that's a PEBKAC).

Comment: That said, I would not be at all certain that crypttab would reread at precisely the correct point in the mounting process, and, of-course, if that file is compromised while the system is online, it can be used to recover the data later.  (I don't have a solution to the OP question though - indeed its something I battled with as well)

Comment: Today I found out that Michael Gebetsroither <michael@mgeb.org> has written a script for caching the passphrase. This script can be found here: https://github.com/gebi/keyctl_keyscript  Unfortunately I was yet unable to get this to work on my Kubuntu 14.04 LTS laptop.  May be I will spend some more time fiddling with it later.

Comment: Additional **update** information: When I asked this question over 4 years ago, I was running Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS as I described in my previous comment.  February 2020 I installed [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org) on a new SSD and used the same LUKS passphrase as I already had on the other HDD.  After editing the `/etc/crypttab` file and adding the additional HDD it worked out of the box: qubes OS asks only once for the passphrase during boot.

Answer (score 1):

That's not exactly the info you are looking for but if you *store the passphrase for the second disk in a keyfile on the already encrypted root filesystem on the SSD and refer to it in the /etc/crypttab file* this info might help: I just checked and the key isn't present on the initrd file. AFAIK, it's only securely stored in the encrypted root filesystem so this option might be a secure one after all.

Answer (score 1):

For reference this guide worked for me like a charm:
https://davidyat.es/2015/04/03/encrypting-a-second-hard-drive-on-ubuntu-14-10-post-install/

I just followed the steps and it works :)